# Why nilObject isEqual nilObject return no?

Tags: objective-c, null

When I use this code:

```
    NSString *a = nil;
    NSString *b = nil;
    if([a isEqual:b]){
        NSLog(@"YES");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"NO");
    }
```

The console print "NO" I don't understand this behavior. Could you explain me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules for sending messages to `nil`are as follows:

(Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW7)

- If the method returns any pointer type, any integer scalar of size less than or equal to `sizeof(void*)`, a `float`, a `double`, a `long double`, or a `long long`, then a message sent to `nil` returns `0`.
- If the method returns a `struct`, as defined by the [Mac OS X ABI Function Call Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/Conceptual/LowLevelABI/000-Introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002437-SW1) to be returned in registers, then a message sent to `nil` returns `0.0` for every field in the `struct`. Other `struct` data types will not be filled with zeros.
- If the method returns anything other than the aforementioned value types, the return value of a message sent to `nil` is undefined.

(Thanks [@Jim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8427/jim))

So for example, if you do this:

```
if(![nil someMessageThatAlwaysReturnsTrue]) {
   NSLog(@"Watch this.");
}
```

It will print out  "Watch this" every time.

Comment: This is not technically true.  In some cases behaviour is undefined - see the link in my answer.  It is always true when the method you are calling returns an object, as in this case.

Comment: @Jim Hmm, interesting. TIL :)

Answer (score 4):

See [Sending Messages to nil](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW7)
 in [The Objective-C Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/).  When you send a message to an object that is `nil` and the method returns an object, the expression evaluates to `nil` itself, which is equivalent to `0`, which is equivalent to `NO`.

Answer (score 1):

What does `[a isEqual:b]` actually mean?

It means, send the `isEqual` message, with the parameter `b`, to the object `a`.

And sending any message to a `nil` object returns `nil`. Which is false (NO).